# Saving my current exact webpage for later use

Tags: html

I would like to know if it is possible to save a webpage exactly as I have left it and reload later on the exact same way?

To be specific, I'm on a forum with a quick reply function at the bottom of each thread page. If I typed in some content in the quick reply box, would it be possible for me to save that page and open it up later with my reply already in the quick reply box?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  You need JS, AJAX, and a database.

Comment: @SLaks I'm pretty sure AJAX and the DB can be avoided, you can store it to the local storage for example and restore from there.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: You're right, unless he wants to save across machines.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As long as I can load it up from my computer, that's fine. If it's not too hard, how would I go about doing that? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I genuinely don't know.

Comment: @xseed It's not a stupid question but it _does_ require you to know some JavaScript and some DOM API - if you already do see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't the forum owner, to make a script that will make an autosave, than you should add a extension/plugin/add-on to your browser.

For example i am using this http://getlazarus.com/download